# Mysql large dataset query with column condition which is not indexed

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table named `user` with 20 million rows in total.
The table info is `id, name, ctime` and only `id` is indexed.

I'd like to query `select min(id) from user where citme > 1521882950`.

The result time is around 7-10 seconds.

When I query with `select min(id) from user`, the result time is around 10ms. I think the reason is because `id` is indexed by mysql. So the query is fast.

Since indexing `ctime` is not so meaningful for the table, I am thinking if there is another way to query in less than 1 second without indexing the `ctime` column?

From mysql dev page, I found this explaining about [indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html),  I don't know how to apply the greater condition.

```
SELECT MIN(key_part2),MAX(key_part2)
FROM tbl_name WHERE key_part1=10;
```

Answer (score 1):

For

```
SELECT MIN(key_part2),MAX(key_part2)
    FROM tbl_name WHERE key_part1=10;
```

you need

```
INDEX(key_part1, key_part2)
```

What you have is

```
SELECT MIN(key_part2)                     -- id
    FROM tbl_name WHERE key_part1=10;     -- ctime
```

which needs

```
INDEX(ctime, id)
```

However, InnoDB's secondary indexes automatically include the PK, so saying merely

```
INDEX(ctime)
```

happens to have the same effect.  (I prefer to say `INDEX(ctime, id)` as a clue to the reader that I need that pair.)

"Since indexing ctime is not so meaningful for the table" -- Well, it was meaningful for that one query!  So, index it.

Without the index, the entire table will be read to process the query.

With the index, *only one* row in the `INDEX` will be read to get the result.

That's about as extreme as it gets (having vs not having an index).

Meanwhile,

```
select min(id) from user
```

uses the `PRIMARY KEY` and reads *only one* row to get the answer.

"I am thinking if there is another way to query in less than 1 second without indexing the ctime column?"  Why does it matter?  Simply add the index and be done with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I asked someone around. It seems there is no better way to query a column without index within seconds. For my case, the best way for mysql to query fast is indexing the column `ctime`.

If there is a better answer, please update.